# IDP Metadata losing port in location URLs when using https

Tags: keycloak, opensaml, spring-security-saml2

I'm testing an application that uses spring-security-saml and using KeyCloak as the indentity provider for testing. KeyCloak by default runs on both http, and https with a self-signed cert.

When retrieving the metadata over https in a browser at https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml/descriptor it correctly returns the following:

```
<md:EntitiesDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Name="urn:keycloak">
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:KeyName>phlmLKZ2YqrT_0hsZQYSpBPrZxPmgNdI3I2AmPQFjg8</ds:KeyName>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
</md:EntitiesDescriptor>
```

When I give that same metadata location to my application, it ends up trying to send me to a URL without port 8543, even though that port was on all the locations above:

https://localhost/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml

Debugging into the OpenSAML code, it looks like the ports are lost after returning from line 460 of AbstractMetadataProvider where it parses the raw IDP metadata:

```
protected XMLObject unmarshallMetadata(InputStream metadataInput) throws UnmarshallingException {
        try {
            log.trace("Parsing retrieved metadata into a DOM object");
            Document mdDocument = parser.parse(metadataInput);
```

Is there any way to control this and have it honor the port in the metadata xml?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging further, the port was also not present in the raw response that HTTPMetadataProvider obtained.

It turns out the issue was due to misconfiguration of the HttpClient which was not sending the port in the host header, so Keycloak was then not responding with a port.